# Rails cancan load_and_authorize_resource not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, cancan

I committed to customize a project, which has cancan authentication. 
my cancan `ability.rb`

```
if user.has_role? :super_admin
  can :manage, :all
elsif user.has_role? :site_admin
  can :manage, [User, Listing]
elsif user.has_role? :manager
  can :manage, Listing, :user_id => user.id
end
```

my models:

`User`

`Listing has_many :listing_types`

`ListingType belongs_to :listing`

now i created a new model `ListingDetail belongs_to :listing`

controller `listing_details` which has `load_and_authorize_resource`
when i access this page from manager role, it redirect to login page
(in my admin namespace's index controller's index action i redirected to login page for nil user )
why this is happening?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot access the `ListingDetail` controller as a manager because you've only been granted permissions on the `Listing` object. To add permissions for `ListingDetails` only on `Listings` you own, add the following to your manager permissions:

```
can :manage, ListingDetail, :listing => {:user_id => user.id}
```